# Nuxt root page (parent) is not rendered for child route despite using <nuxt-child> in the parent

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a simple setup of files:

**Pages structure:**

```
./pages/index.vue     // root page to be displayed for '/'
./pages/child.vue     // sub-page to be displayed inside index.vue for '/child'
```

**`index.vue`:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This is parent</p>
    <some-component-from-components></some-component-from-components>
    <nuxt-child />
   </div>
</template>
```

**`child.vue`:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This is Child</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

I expect that for `'/'` route the `index.vue` will be displayed and for `'/child'` route `index.vue` with embedded `child.vue` in the `<nuxt-child />` placeholder. `'/'` route works as expected, however for `'/child'` just `child.vue` is displayed.

Why? Does `<nuxt-child />` not work with root page or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest the `child` component inside of the `index` directory if you want that kind of behavior. Here, you do have both at the same level, hence why you cannot nest one into the other.

More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtchild-component

More details about the structure of your routes: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#nested-routes